Inconsistent Start of Week Date in Power BI
= Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Day Name", "Start of Week", each Date.StartOfWeek([Date],Day.Monday), type date)

I have implemented the following M code in my Power Query to set the start of the week to Monday.
In the Power Query Editor, the dates appear correctly as 30/06/2020. However, after closing and applying the changes, in the table view, the "Start of Week" column shows the date as 29/06/2020, which is not what I expected.
Why does the date change from 30/06/2020 in the editor to 29/06/2020 in the table view?
What could be causing this discrepancy?

Please edit your question to add, as text, a data sample and the associated m-code (from the Advanced Editor) so that we can try to reproduce your problem. I am sure you are aware that 30/06/2020 is a Tuesday and 29/06/2020 is a Monday. Might you just be looking at the wrong column?
